# How to connect a SATA III port to a SAS hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid, sata, sas

On my motherboard, the ASUS Z9PA-D8, it says that it has a row of 8 SAS ports for connecting to SAS hard drives.

[image]

I'm talking about the line of blue things running horizontally in the bottom right of the image. They clearly look like SATA III ports. And I can connect a SATA III 6.0 GB/S data transfer cable into them. But, when I go to connect them to a SAS hard drive, it doesn't work.

What kind of cable should I buy to connect from this port to a usual SAS hard drive?

On page 51 of the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiBvZmx-cDnAhWOuVkKHZrfB_gQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdlcdnets.asus.com%2Fpub%2FASUS%2Fmb%2FSocket2011%2FZ9PA-D8%2FManual%26QVL%2FE7572_Z9PA-D8_for_web.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3vJMcrDZTPT0AfjFnyjvLU), it calls them "PSAS connectors", but I don't know what that means, and it's not on the web. I just want to know how to get these SAS hard drives working with this board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On my motherboard, the ASUS Z9PA-D8, it says that it has a row of 8 SAS ports for connecting to SAS hard drives.

Your getting confused.  Your motherboard documentation indicates that the [ASUS Pike 2008](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/PIKE_2008/) add-on card is required for those 8 ports to work.

> What kind of cable should I buy to connect from this port to a usual SAS hard drive?

You don’t need a cable.  You need the optional Pike 2008 add-on card suggested by your manual.  **Those 8 ports require the ASUS Pike 2008 card to function.**

> On page 51 of the documentation, it calls them "PSAS connectors", but I don't know what that means, and it's not on the web. I just want to know how to get these SAS hard drives working with this board.

It also explicitly describes what a PSAS SAS port is.

> PSAS connectors are for the SAS signal cables for SAS hard disk drives that allows up to 6Gb/s of data transfer rate.